# Как в hibernate использовать rowset из jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, pagination

Возможно вопрос неправильный и я бы его не задал, если бы не нужно было через три дня сдавать задание - crud-приложение с пагинацией. По условию нужно использовать hibernate. Хочу сделать server-side pagination.

Comment: String hql = "FROM Employee";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setFirstResult(1);
query.setMaxResults(10);
List results = query.list();  Только мне не понятно как это работает внутри, как обычный limit или кэшируется или что-то еще

Comment: В настройках Hibernate можно задать параметр `show_sql` и тогда вы сможете видеть какие запросы отправляются базе данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно сделать пагинацию и использовать при этом Hibernate, то логично было бы гуглить по запросу "hibernate pagination".

Раз вариант:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from SomeEntity");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(10);
List<SomeEntity> entities = query.list();
```

Два вариант:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from SomeEntity e order by e.name");
int pageSize = 10;

ScrollableResults resultScroll = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
resultScroll.first();
resultScroll.scroll(0);

List<SomeEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < pageSize; i++) {
    entities.add((SomeEntity) resultScroll.get(0));
    if (!resultScroll.next())
        break;
}
```